# Preserving a JOGL Context

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I want to be able to preserve an OpenGL context through the process of changing a window's fullscreen and decoration. Since I have to dispose of the window when I want to change the decoration (which must also be done when changing to full screen to have no pseudo decorated fullscreen), the context seems to be destroyed. Is there a way to preserve a context in such a way that I never need to have some init code run twice?

Answer (score 0):

You should use NEWT and maybe GLStateKeeper. Please rather ask questions about JOGL on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org). Sven will be probably more able than me to explain to you how to use GLStateKeeper if it is really necessary in your case.

Comment: Since I can not set a resizable flag for a NEWT window, NEWT kind of has not the features I want. --- I want to be able to dynamically adjust every single aspect of the window around an OpenGL canvas without it's context ever being recreated so I put away strain from the person using my code having to think about having to reinitialize his abstraction layer above mine above JOGLs.

Comment: There is already a request for enhancement about this feature: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=637 Moreover, what you want to achieve is unable with a pure AWT drawable.

Comment: Well is there something like a mixed drawable that can be used in an AWT window but has the stability of your NEWT ones? If all this fails, I am right now inclined to make my own decoration in an undecorated NEWT window - that should at least make sure that I have full control over the look and feel of any window that I make and I can boast with featuring in-engine rendered decoration ...

Comment: Yes, you can use NewtCanvasAWT :)